# Error: Uncaught in promise: Invalid link: EditPage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

```
menu.html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="light">
    <ion-title align="center" class="fontHead">
      Report
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
    <ion-fab right>
        <button ion-fab class="n" color="fab" (click)="addMenu()"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab>


<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let menu of menuList | async">
       <ion-item (click)="detailsMenu(menu)">
        <h2><ion-icon name="calendar" item-start></ion-icon>Date: <br> {{ menu.date }}</h2>
        <p><ion-icon name="clipboard" item-start></ion-icon>Customer: <br> {{ menu.CustName }} </p>
        <p class><ion-icon name="information-circle" item-start></ion-icon>Done by: <br> {{ menu.AdminName }}</p>
        <p><ion-icon name="information-circle" item-start></ion-icon>Status: <br> {{ menu.status }}</p>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item-options>
        <button ion-button color="edit" navPush="EditPage" [navParams]="{menu:menu}">
       <ion-icon name="build"></ion-icon>Edit</button>
        </ion-item-options>
     </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: EditPage

I dont know why it doesnt work on this page my other page with the similar code working but this page only the edit link is not working. I dont know what the problem is.. can you help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPush/), you should set

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="EditPage"></button>
```

instead of

```
<button ion-button navPush="EditPage"></button>
```